# What's up with the python tax program I wrote

Tags: python

What's up with this tax rate program I'm writing to be precise I'm trying to figure out why the 2.5% isn't showing up on the program when I run it it shows up as a different percentage so here's what I've got so far

`

## Script Name: Tax Program

```
# Author : 
# Purpose: The purpose of this program is to ask the user to enter the amount of a item purchase.
# The program should then compute the state and county sales tax. Assume the
# state sales tax is 5 percent and the county sales tax is 2.5 percent. The program
# should display the amount of the purchase, the state sales tax, the county
# sales tax, the total sales tax and the total of the sale (which is the sum of
# the amount of purchase plus the total sales tax)
# Use the value 0.05 and 0.025

# Display "Enter item_price Amount"
# Input item_price
# Display "state tax is 5%"
# Set state_tax= 0.05
# Display "county_tax is 2.5%"
# Set county_sales tax = 0.025


county_tax = 0.025
state_tax = 0.05
tax_rate= county_tax + state_tax

#Ask User to enter item price and store it in the item price varible
item_price = float(input("Please enter the price of your item"))
item_price =int(100* item_price)
total_price = item_price*(1 + tax_rate)

#Calculate item price at .05, .025, and .075 tax rate

print("Your Purchase Amount was ${:0.2f}".format(item_price/100))      
print("Your County Tax Rate was {}%".format(int(county_tax * 1000 * 20/100)))
print("Your State Tax Rate was{}%".format(int(state_tax * 1000 * 20/100)))
print("Your Total Sales Cost is ${:0.2}".format(total_price/100))
print("Your Total Tax Rate was{}%".format(int(tax_rate * 1000 * 20/100)))
```

Comment: You would need to show your inputs and what you expected as output and what you got instead

Comment: Why arw you making so sophisticated calculation? And have you tried to enter an item price of, say, 10? You get then `$2.7e+01` as Total Sales Cost in the output. I don't think it's what you'd like to see.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are multiplying the values by `20/100` for no apparent reason so your 0.025 i.e. 2.5% is shown *.2